# aggregating and ifelse functions in R

Tags: r

Attached is some R code:

```
temp_df <- data.frame(c("A","A","A","G","G","Z","Z"),
                    c("B","D","E","R","S","Y","U"),
                    c(1.5,1.1,0.8,0.2,0.8,0.9,0.1),
                    c(0.8,0.4,1.5,1.2,1.2,0.2,0.3),
                    c(2.7,2.7,2.7,2.4,2.4,0.5,0.5),
                    c("YES","NO","NO","NO","NO","YES","YES"))

colnames(temp_df) <- c("PERSON_1","PERSON_2","VALUE_1",
                     "VALUE_2","TOTAL_2","DECISION_2")
```

What I am trying to do is create a new column called "NEW_DECISION_1" based on the following rules:

For the people in column 1 ("PERSON_1"), if the value of the corresponding values in column 5 ("TOTAL_2") is greater than or equal to 2.0 and there is a least one "YES" in the corresponding values in column 6 ("DECISION_2"), then the value for the "NEW_DECISION_1" column will be "YES", and if these criteria are not satisfied, then they will get a "NO" value.

So for the A person in column 1, since the values in column 5 is 2.7 and there is at least one "YES" in the corresponding values in column 6 then the value in the new column will be "YES".

For the G person in column 1, since the values in column 5 is 2.4 but since there are no "YES" values in the corresponding values in column 6, the value in the new column will be "NO".

For the Z person in column 1, since the values in column 5 is 1.0 and there is at least one "YES" in the corresponding values in column 6, the value in the new column will be "NO".
So the new table will be:

```
temp_df$NEW_DECISION_1 <- c("YES","YES","YES","NO","NO","NO","NO")
temp_df
```

I am thinking of some sort of aggregation rule but I am not sure what function to use to search for "least one "YES"".

If you need any more information or clarification, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution with `ddply`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(temp_df, .(PERSON_1), transform,
      NEW_DECISION_1 = c("NO", "YES")[(TOTAL_2 >= 2 &
                                       sum(DECISION_2 == "YES") > 0) + 1])

#   PERSON_1 PERSON_2 VALUE_1 VALUE_2 TOTAL_2 DECISION_2 NEW_DECISION_1
# 1        A        B     1.5     0.8     2.7        YES            YES
# 2        A        D     1.1     0.4     2.7         NO            YES
# 3        A        E     0.8     1.5     2.7         NO            YES
# 4        G        R     0.2     1.2     2.4         NO             NO
# 5        G        S     0.8     1.2     2.4         NO             NO
# 6        Z        Y     0.9     0.2     0.5        YES             NO
# 7        Z        U     0.1     0.3     0.5        YES             NO
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the base R solution:

```
result <- by(temp_df, 
  INDICES=temp_df$PERSON_1, 
  FUN=function(x) 
    within(x, DECISION_1 <- ifelse(any(grepl('YES', DECISION_2)) & TOTAL_2 >= 2, 
                                   'YES', 'NO')))
do.call(rbind, result)

#        PERSON_1 PERSON_2 VALUE_1 VALUE_2 TOTAL_2 DECISION_2 DECISION_1
#    A.1        A        B     1.5     0.8     2.7        YES        YES
#    A.2        A        D     1.1     0.4     2.7         NO        YES
#    A.3        A        E     0.8     1.5     2.7         NO        YES
#    G.4        G        R     0.2     1.2     2.4         NO         NO
#    G.5        G        S     0.8     1.2     2.4         NO         NO
#    Z.6        Z        Y     0.9     0.2     0.5        YES         NO
#    Z.7        Z        U     0.1     0.3     0.5        YES         NO
```

Comment: Cheers mplourde. Your reply was very quick and accurate but was only allowed to tick one of the answers. Still it is very useful for future codes :)